# How to narrow object property accessed by variable?

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in TS to narrow an object property which has been dynamically accessed using a variable, to exclude `undefined` values for example ?

The following code ([TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/mbrJ8m)):

```
interface Dict {
  [k: string]: {
    prop?: number;
  };
}

const d: Dict = {};

let a = "item";
const b = a;
const c = "item";

if (d[a].prop) {
  d[a].prop++ // Nope
}

if (d[b].prop) {
  d[b].prop++ // Neither
}

if (d[c].prop) {
  d[c].prop++ // OK
}
```

illustrates that when accessing the dictionary/object values using a variable or a constant which is a copy of this variables, TypeScript gives us an error about potentially `undefined` value even if tried to narrow down. It only works when using a constant defined from a literal.

Is there a/What is the solution to avoid this behaviour ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save `d[a]` to a constant, check that, and reuse it:

```
const entry = d[a];
if (entry.prop) {
    entry.prop++; // OK
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=2&module=0&ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCLAWZBvAsAKGSOQG0BrALmQGcwpQBzAXSr0OI4AcoB7TgfiogArgFsARtADcBDgF8Z+OQQIIeIWsgAmVdJmQBeHApX4ANhCxxDyAETBIo24tXrNEcFACeNrSThMisAwyAAUHnReAHTcfACUOLLEEd4xvJwA1BlSyAD0ucgA8gDSBMr4QA)

That works even though `a` is not constant because `entry` is, so TypeScript's flow analysis can see that `entry.prop` has been narrowed.

Comment: Working perfectly, thanks! I forgot about JS reference-based assignment, so I thought I won't be able to modify `d` without narrowing it directly ^^' Accepting this answer then